# Swift: how to implement protocols from cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, protocols

I am trying to implement the CVCalendar cocoapod (https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) and in the instructions it says:

'CVCalendar requires an implementation of two protocols CVCalendarViewDelegate and CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate, please implement both.' but does not give instructions on how to do this. I am new to programming and am struggling to see how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

A protocol is basically a set of methods that your class must implement in order to adopt that protocol.

You should also look at their example which is located here:

https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/tree/master/CVCalendar%20Demo

If you look in their example in ViewController.swift line 52 there is the implementation of both CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate protocols.

Comment: In the example they seem to add it as an extension, which gives me an error

Comment: 'Declaration is only valid at file scope'

Answer (score 0):

If you class is named `MyClass` you need to declare it as:

```
class MyClass: CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {
...
}
```

instead of `...` you'd put your basic code + implemented methods of those delegates. To see what methods you need to implement, open declaration of delegates (command + click on the delegate class name)

Comment: I tried that but my project doesnt recognise those two protocols even though I have added them to the project. It says declaration is only valid at file scope

Comment: try add:
`import CVCalendar`

Comment: ah yeah that was the problem. Stupid mistake on my behalf! thanks for helping